# jquery contains not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to look for a div on a page containing a given piece of text in a loop (metric.DisplayGroup), and if it's not there, create one (inside a table cell). Using my code below, my console shows that I'm correctly finding the elements and I can see my new elements appearing, but the next time round the loop, the check doesn't find the new ones I've added and so creates more.

Any ideas?
thanks!

```
console.log("looking for " + metric.DisplayGroup);
if ($("div:not(:contains('" + metric.DisplayGroup + "'))")) {
     console.log("adding: " + metric.DisplayGroup);
     $(ChartTable).append("<tr><td colspan='3'><div>" + metric.DisplayGroup + "</div></td></tr>");
                    }
```

Comment: what do you mean next time? How is the "next time" called?

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle/demo? Are you re-running the selector itself each iteration? If that's not run again, it won't know of any new elements

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use event delegation to find the newly-added elements. jQuery only acts on those that are available on document.ready otherwise.

If you feel like posting an HTML snippet we could work up a demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7y2Q9/

```
// metric.DisplayGroup = ??
```